Excel 365 - display PivotTable summary as percentage of non-zero data in the range
I have a table of timestamped data, where one column is a zero or one.

I'm trying to analyze the data in a pivot table, and I can summarize the 3rd column using the built in min,max,and average functions.

I'm trying to get the 4th column in the table output to summarize the percentage of time the 2nd column of the source data is non-zero. I've tried the Value Field Settings options such as "Count of IsUp" and "Show Values as Percentage", but it shows percentage of the entire data set, not of the summarized group (e.g. the current day).
I can derive the correct value for 21-November outside of the pivottable with this formuala
=COUNTIF(B2:B3595,"1")/COUNTA(B5:B3595)


Is there any way to achieve this in the Value Field Settings for the "Count of IsUp" column in the PivotTable output?
